# Flask not picking up updated JSON

Tags: python, json, flask

When JSON file is changed, Flask is not rending pages using the updated JSON. How can I fix this? Python version 2.7.6 . Flask version 0.9 . 
My repository is available at https://github.com/harishvc/githubanalytics

```
#Starting Flask
#!flask/bin/python
from app import app
app.run(debug = True)
```

Comment: You'll have to show the code.

Comment: Please show your work, code samples that you tried, version of flash... any info helps understanding your question will help you get an answer that fits your needs

Comment: I think you want something like two-way binding. It probably doesn't work that way automatically. Somewhere in your code you have to load the updated JSON.

Comment: @vaultah I have updated my question with more information and link to GitHub.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is not that the JSON is not updated when it changed, but rather in that your code only loads that file only just once, specifically right at import of that module and never ever again.  The obvious is bound to happen.

To better assist you, you should include the relevant parts of your code into the question and not just the link, which I will do for you here:

```
with open('path/to/jsonfile.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

mydata = []
for row in data['rows']:
    mydata.append({'name': result_row[0], 'count' : result_row[1],})

@app.route('/')
@app.route('/index')
def index():
    return render_template("index.html", data=mydata)
```

That's essentially your code.  No where in your `index` route handler will reload that json and repopulate the `mydata` list with the new data you might have added into your JSON file.  So, create a method that will do that

```
mydata = []

def refresh_data():
    mydata.clear()  # clear the list on the module scope

    with open('path/to/jsonfile.json') as f:
        data = json.load(f)

    for row in data['rows']:
        mydata.append({'name': result_row[0], 'count' : result_row[1],})
```

Then simply get the route handler to call that `refresh_data` function:

```
@app.route('/')
@app.route('/index')
def index():
    refresh_data()
    return render_template("index.html", data=mydata)
```

I personally would take this a step further and rather have `refresh_data` load something and then save the data onto some list locating on some other scope, I would have it return the data to make this safer to use.  This suggestion, along with other Error/Exception handling and other clean-up is left to your exercise.